# Confusion with amplifying differential outputs with an op-amp

Tags: operational-amplifier

A three wire source has differential output but uni-polar(only one signal wire varies wrt AGND). Ground wire is AGND, the the other two is signal SG and the reference SGref. I'm trying to amplify the transducer signal with a gain of ten by using a non-inverting amplifier.

Since the transducer is not single ended output I'm bit confused. Which topology is correct?

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fZUdaf.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

At page 41 [here](https://www.ati-ia.com/app_content/documents/9620-05-DAQ.pdf) shows the differential wiring of channels and at page 37 it says:

> The transducer outputs are designed to work with a differential input
>   to the DAQ system for best performance. Transducer outputs are
>   ground-referenced differential signals. The output impedance of each
>   DAQ signal is 100Ω

(I checked the output and only SG moves wrt to AGND but not SEGref so I think it is unipolar even though differential ended)

Comment: Try simulating it and add common-mode noise equally onto both feed wires via a 1 nF capacitor.

Comment: It's better to use an opamp connected to amplify differentially when you're using a differential source.

Comment: @Neil_UK Do you mean differential amplifier like this topology http://www.circuitstoday.com/wp-content/uploads/2011/11/differential-amplifier-using-one-opamp.png ??

Comment: Which transducer (datasheet) and what is your DAQ ?

Comment: First circuit will create contention between the feedback and the input signal. I think the second one is the correct option. If you want to use both the differential outputs of the transducer use fully differential design, otherwise an amplifier without feedback.

Comment: @sarthak Could you give me an example for the fully differential design topology?

Comment: @user1999 Yes, with Rf/R1 = R3/R2. However, that simple circuit has different input impedances on the two inputs, so it's only really useful when the source voltage is much lower impedance than the input impedances. For a high source impedance, it's better to use a [two-amp or three-amp INA](https://electronicsforu.com/electronics-projects/electronics-design-guides/whats-difference-operational-amplifiers-instrumentation-amplifiers/3)